# Why crypto.createHash() is not writable until setEncoding() is called?

Tags: node.js, node-request, node-crypto, node-streams

I use `request` [package](https://github.com/request/request) with `crypto`. It seems that `request` implements legacy `stream` protocol and [don't write](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/legacy.js#L15) any data to the piped destination until it's `writable`.

```
Stream.prototype.pipe = function(dest, options) {
  var source = this;

  function ondata(chunk) {
    if (dest.writable) {
      if (false === dest.write(chunk) && source.pause) {
        source.pause();
      }
    }
  }
...
```

So, if I use the next code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'); 
const request = require('request');

var hasher = crypto.createHash('sha256'); 
// Uncomment the line below to fix!
// hasher.setEncoding('hex');
console.log(hasher.writable); 
request('http://ya.ru').pipe(hasher).on('finish', function() {
    console.log('Hash is', hasher.read()); 
});
```

it produces the `sha256('')` (i.e. from empty value). But when I use `hasher.setEncoding('hex')` the code produces `sha256(<response_body>)` and `hasher.writable` gives `true`.

I can't understand what is the reason of acting this way? And where is that stated in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there was a [bug](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/12269#issuecomment-292602694) in Node. Here is even smaller code sample to reproduce it:

```
var hasher = crypto.createHash('sha256'); 
const _ = hasher._writableState;  // we don't even have to call .setEnconding() here
console.log(hasher.writable);
```

Stream1 implementation [required](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/legacy.js#L15) `this.writable` to be true in the destination stream.

```
Stream.prototype.pipe = function(dest, options) {
  var source = this;

  function ondata(chunk) {
    if (dest.writable) {
      if (false === dest.write(chunk) && source.pause) {
        source.pause();
      }
    }
  }

  source.on('data', ondata);
  ...
```

Calling to `hasher.setEncoding('hex')` (or any other access to `this._writableState`) triggered a call to the actual constructor of the stream. Before it `this.writable` was `undefined`.